# Shopware 6 Admin API: How mulltiplicate two fields and select sum the sum

Tags: mysql, shopware6

The [aggregation reference offer `sum(field)`](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/core-reference/dal-reference/aggregations-reference#sum-aggregation).
I'm looking for the right aggregation for an query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(`filedA` * `fieldB`) AS total
FROM myTable
WHERE id = 1234
```

Can i do achieve this with the given aggregations? If not, how?

Answer (score 1):

You want to multiply one field with another of one row?

Then aggregation is not what you are looking for because it aggregates (sum, avg, ...) of a set of values (multiple rows, not columns)

What about this?

SQL

```sql
SELECT `filedA` * `fieldB` AS total
FROM myTable
WHERE id = 1234;
```

PHP

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$entities = $repository->search($criteria, $context)->getEntities();

foreach ($entities as $entity) {
   var_dump(
       $entity->getFiledA() * $entity->getFiledB()
   );
}
```